What is the difference between verbs "will" and "would"?
What is the difference between verbs "will" and "would"? I have two examples below:

I am trying to talk to him, but he won't listen.
I was trying to talk to him, but he wouldn't listen.

Does the second variant mean that clause "..., but he wouldn't listen." refers to the future tense in relation to the first sentence and simultaneously referes to past tense in relation to current time while in the first construction clause "..., but he won't to listen." refers to future tense in relation to current time?

This is the will that means "want to". It does not have anything to do with the future.

Does "I am trying to talk to him, but he won't listen." equivalent to "I am trying to talk to him, but he doesn't want to listen."?

Here he won't listen is like saying that he refuses to listen.

Will here means is willing to.

He refuses to listen (now).

He refused to listen (in the past).



For example, I can say:
"We believed that he would win the race but the reality was different."
but I can't say:
"We believed that he will win the race but the reality was different."
Right?

That's a different meaning of will/would! What you say is correct, but it has nothing to do with your original question about He won't listen.

Modal verb "would" is more difficult than "will".

I can't understand why I must use "wouldn't", not "will not" in the second case.

@АлександрСкворцов You have to use wouldn't not won't because you already established that everything was in the past when you began I was trying to talk to him. It does not make any sense to swap tenses between present and past; you set things in the past and now you must stay there for the rest of the narration about it. Would is the same verb as will, so it is not any harder; would is merely the past of will, which is the present.

Why can't I say "We believed that he will win the race but the reality was different."?

You can't say  that someone will win a race which has already happened.

Probably, thanks to "..., but the reality was different." I may only use modal verb "would". If this sentence had lacked, then I could have possibly used verb "will", I think.

"We believe that he will win the race tomorrow." "We believed that he would win the race yesterday" (implies (but he didn't).

I also read that modal verb "would" may have the same meaning like verb "used to". Also sometimes verb "wouldn't" means "refused to do something" and would means "insisted on something". Is it true?

Your original question was about 'won't/wouldn't' meaning 'refuses/refused to', and so was my answer. You confused the issue by starting to ask about 'will' as the future tense.

The explanations to follow are based on A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, Quirk et al, 1985.
Those two verb forms are modal, the first being the present of the verbal (modal) auxiliary "will" and the second the past form of the same auxiliary.  No notion of futurity is implied in these two sentences.
It is true, or let's say, rather, evident to most, that the notion of futurity can be found in the modal use of "will" and this is so in more than one way; for instance, in the common FUTURE predictive sense of "will" a sentence such as

"You won't feel better after you take this medicine, it is not good enough."

involves the idea of a future happening.
But this is not so in the OP's sentences. In those sentences the auxiliary introduces the modal nuance of VOLITION.
In the very words of Quirk et al (§ 4.57),

"[…] three different subsenses may be distinguished. The volitional range of will extends from the'weak volition'of WILLINGNESS to the 'strong volition' of INSISTENCE. Between these two, there is the more usual volitional sense of INTENTION, which often combines with a sense of prediction […]."

This is directly furthered in the same section by the following.

(bl) INTENTION

I'll write as soon as I can.
We won't stay longer than two hours.
The manager said he would phone me after lunch.

(b2) WILLINGNESS

Will/ Would you help me to address these letters?
I'll do it, if you like.

This meaning is common in requests and offers. […]
(b3) INSISTENCE

If you 'will go out without your overcoat, what can you expect?
She 'would keep interrupting me.

This somewhat rare use implies wilfulness on the part of the subject
referent. The auxiliary is always stressed, and cannot be contracted to
'll or 'd. In this case, the past form would expresses past time, rather
than tentativeness or politeness.

It can be seen from the above that "insistence" (b3) is the modal notion imparted, in both sentences, and that moreover, this insistence (on not wanting to listen), has nothing to do with the future in the first case (a state present in fact: he has been insisting in his refusal not to listen, he will continue to do so now, and probably will go on doing so for some time to come), but does have something to do with the past in the second. Moreover, "won't" and "wouldn't" would have to be stressed (as I have no personal certitude on a would-be  absolute necessity to stress those verbal forms I'd greatly appreciate the comments of readers who think themselves entitled to add more specific details or a categorical confirmation concerning that question).
It remains to explain the use of the past "wouldn't".

(CoGEL § 4.61) 'Past time' in other constructions
Outside indirect speech contexts, the behaviour of the past tense modal forms is less predictable. Could and would act as the 'past time' equivalents of can and will;
[…].
(a) CAN - COULD

There were no rules: we  could do just what we wanted.
[= permission]
In those days, a transatlantic voyage could be dangerous.
[= possibility]
Few of the tourists could speak English. [= ability]

(b) WILL - WOULD

Later, he would learn his error. [= prediction; […]
The old lady would sit in front of the television continuously.
[= habitual prediction; […]]
We tried to borrow a boat, but no one would lend us one.
[ = willingness]
He 'would leave the house in a muddle. [= insistence]


The time reference is the past ("I was trying to talk to him"), therefore the past "wouldn't".
Supplement aiming at situating the modality highlighted above within a wider scheme of modal senses
Akin to this notion of insistence to which it is pointed above, the following additional notion of modality remarked upon in a note to the above section from Quirk et al appears to be a complement to keep in mind.

Note
[a] The predictive meaning of will is sometimes weakened, so that it resembles the ability meaning of can:

That's a fine car. How fast will it go?
The new grand stand will hold ten thousand spectators.

The negative of this 'potentiality' sense of will seems to have something of the personificatory force of 'refusal' (ie the negation of willingness):

It's a good piano, but it just won't stay in tune.
I tried to open the door, but the key wvouldn't turn.

It is almost as if the piano or the key had a will of its own.


Both show continuous aspect.
The  period of attempted communication (/advising?) in (2) may well be over now; it is less likely (though not at all impossible) that 'he' is now more receptive.
The  period of attempted communication (/advising?) in (1) is obviously still extant (because 'won't' is used); whether the meaning is iterative ('I keep on trying ...') or immediate ('Here's the phone; you have a word with him') is uncertain.

Look at this example, please: "She destroyed the files so that I wouldn't learn its content."
Does the verb "wouldn't" merely reflect future situation in relation to destruction in past, but both of these situations are just past in relation to current time?

@АлександрСкворцов No, it means something more along the lines of "so that I was not going to learn its content".
